# Appending dynamic headers Angular Apollo

Tags: angular, rxjs, apollo

During my angular application startup process, I need to asynchronously get a config file which contains my graphql URI (uri is generated during CI/CD pipeline). To achieve this I can use the APP_INITIALIZER token to do some async loading. This works well enough to setup a default apollo client.

```
export function createApollo(apolloOptionsService: ApolloOptionsService) {
  return async (): Promise<any> => {
    return await lastValueFrom(apolloOptionsService.createApollo$()
      .pipe(filter(val => !!val))
      .pipe(take(1)));
  };
}

export function getApolloOptions(apolloOptionsService: ApolloOptionsService) {
  return apolloOptionsService.getApolloOtionsValue();
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ApolloModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    ApolloOptionsService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [ApolloOptionsService],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: getApolloOptions,
      deps: [ApolloOptionsService]
    },
    Apollo
  ]
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

**Problem**: To get an access token, I need to make a call using the Auth0 library. I cannot use the Auth0 library during the `createApollo` factory method because the auth0 service hasn't been instantiated yet because of the `APP_INITIALIZER` startup sequence.

As a work around, I've decided to take the approach of appending the headers at the request level.

```
return forkJoin([this.userRole$, this.getAccessToken$()])
  .pipe(
    switchMap(res => {
      const roles = res[0];
      const accessToken = res[1] as string;

  return this.apollo
    .watchQuery({
      query: gql`
        ${ApiQueries.getStuff}
      `,
      variables: {
        selected_user_role_id: roles?.rid,
        tenant_id: roles?.tenantId
      },
      context: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        },
      }
    })
    .valueChanges.pipe(
      map((result: any) => {
        return ApiParser.parseStuffResult(result);
      }),
      catchError((error) => this.errorHandler('getStuff$', error)),
    );
})
```

);

**Question**:

1. Appending authorization headers on the request level doesn't work and when inspecting the network tab, i can see my headers aren't there, why?
2. Is there another way to get access to a jwt during startup?

Side note: I've verified that the headers are present and my requests work if I temporarily hard code a jwt in my apollo client setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to append headers you should do so in an Apollo-Client [link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/)

Here's a simple `authLink`:

```
const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const token = await getToken(); // or however you get your token
  if (token) headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  return { headers };
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Added my own answer with the full implementation for others to use if they wish to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
const basic = setContext((operation, context) => ({
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
  },
}));
// Create an apollo link with the token and uri
const apolloHeaderLink = ApolloLink.from([
  basic,
  this.httpLink.create({ uri: config.someLink})
]);
this.apollo.client.setLink(apolloHeaderLink);
```

Apollo links is what I was looking for. This is how you can create a link that will append headers before the request. I can now append my jwt on a per request basis.